# Count instances of strings in multiple columns python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have the following simple data frame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                   'column_b': ['b', 'x', 'y', 'c', 'z']})


      column_a column_b
0        a        b
1        b        x
2        c        y
3        d        c
4        e        z
```

I'm looking to display the strings which occur in both columns:

```
result = ("b", "c")
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you use: `np.intersect1d(df.column_a, df.column_b)` ?

Comment: @JonClements please add that as an answer.  That is useful and needs to voted upon.

Comment: @piRSquared well, depending if multiple occurrences need preserving or ordering  shouldn't be sorted etc... it's an option, but I'm fairly sure there's a canonical post for this somewhere...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `intersection`

This generalizes over any number of columns.

```
set.intersection(*map(set, map(df.get, df)))

{'b', 'c'}
```

Comment: Alternatively: `set(df.iloc[:, 0]).intersection(*df.iloc[:, 1:])` Or maybe just: `set(df.iloc[:, 0]).intersection(*df.values.T)` as it doesn't matter if you compare the first set to itself really... (bit of a waste but...) - does mean you can pick the column more easily that's probably got the most unique values to reduce comparisons...

Comment: I'd personally go for: `reduce(np.intersect1d, df.values.T)` though :)

Comment: couple of things: 1: `map(df.get, df)` should be faster than `df.values.T` in a general sense.  (I'd have to commit to some testing if I wanted more conviction) 2: `(lambda v: set(v[0]).intersection(*v[1:]))(df.values.T)`

Comment: Depends on how efficient np.intersect1d is though...?

Comment: Yeah, I need to play with that.

Comment: I suspect though that while it should be quicker that because it's working on arrays, is probably doing other stuff, the overhead is going to not be as performant as native sets...

Comment: On `n = 10e3` `np.intersect1d` + `df.values.T` doesn't stand a chance to above. It is A LOT slower.

Comment: (if data is strings, maybe I should add. Updated with post on performance.)

Answer (score 5):

Use  python's `set` object:

```
in_a = set(df.column_a)
in_b = set(df.column_b)
in_both = in_a.intersection(in_b)
```

Comment: Works as a one liner too: `result = set(df.column_a).intersection(df.column_b)`

Comment: This indeed great for the use case OP asked for specific columns as asked.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Sandeep Kadapa's solution. (Without `tolist` and `loc`.)

```
>>> tuple(df['column_a'][df['column_a'].isin(df['column_b'])])                                            
('b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 2):

**Data**

```
n = 10e3

ints = pd.DataFrame({'column_a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] * n,
                   'column_b': [2, 10, 9, 3, 8] * n})

strings = pd.DataFrame({'column_a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] * n,
                   'column_b': ['b', 'x', 'y', 'c', 'z'] * n})
```

**Methods**

```
def using_isin(df):  # @timgeb
    return df['column_a'][df['column_a'].isin(df['column_b'])]

def using_isin_loc_tolist(df):  # @SandeepKadapa
    return df.loc[df['column_a'].isin(df['column_b'].tolist()),'column_a']

def using_melt_groupby(df):  # @W-B
    return df.melt().groupby('value').variable.nunique().loc[lambda x : x>1].index

def using_set_intersection(df):  # @GergesDib, @TBurgins
    return set(df['column_a']).intersection(set(df['column_b']))

def using_set_intersection_map(df):  # @piRSquared
    return set.intersection(*map(set, map(df.get, df)))

def using_reduce_np_intersect(df):  # @JonClements
    return reduce(np.intersect1d, df.values.T)

def using_np_any(df):  # @W-B
    return df.column_a[np.any(df['column_a'].values == df['column_b'].values[:, None], 0)]
```

**Performance if columns contain ints**

```
%timeit -n 10 using_isin(ints)
977 µs ± 164 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 using_reduce_np_intersect(ints)
1.31 ms ± 145 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 using_set_intersection(ints)
1.54 ms ± 68.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 using_set_intersection_map(ints)
1.59 ms ± 59.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 using_isin_loc_tolist(ints)
2.39 ms ± 921 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 using_melt_groupby(ints)
34.2 ms ± 988 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 using_np_any(ints)
4.35 s ± 148 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Performance if columns contain strings**

```
%timeit -n 10 using_set_intersection_map(strings)
1.16 ms ± 35.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 using_intersection_set(strings)
1.2 ms ± 71.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 using_isin(strings)
1.69 ms ± 310 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 using_isin_loc_tolist(strings)
2.15 ms ± 299 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 using_melt_groupby(strings)
35.6 ms ± 1.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 using_reduce_np_intersect(strings)
43 ms ± 1.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 using_np_any(strings)
# too slow to count
```

Comment: np I was trying to figure out why using `np.arrays` didn't really matter in this case so was doing them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and `tuple` as:

```
tuple(df.loc[df['column_a'].isin(df['column_b'].tolist()),'column_a'])
('b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially concept (using sets) the same as the posted answers, but I feel it is a little simpler:

```
set(df.column_a) & set(df.column_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `melt`

```
df.melt().groupby('value').variable.nunique().loc[lambda x : x>1].index
Out[79]: Index(['b', 'c'], dtype='object', name='value')
```

If speed matter

```
s1 = df['column_a'].values
s2 = df['column_b'].values

df.column_a[np.any(s1 == s2[:, None], 0)]
```

Comment: Kind of along the same lines: `df.melt().value.value_counts()[lambda v: v > 1].index`

Comment: Why would you use this seeing that it is slower than slow (like 30 times slower) compared to `set.intersection(set)`?

Comment: @user3471881  I just provide different Idea, also this work when there is more than two columns .

Comment: I get that it works for multiple columns. But we can accomplish that in better ways and this is soooo expensive.

Comment: `df.column[np.any(...)]` is even slower, at least when `n = 10e3`